# Creating PZ-90.02 and PZ-90.11 geodetic datum for QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, russia

I would like to plot maps based on PZ-90.02 and PZ-90.11 in Russia, but in QGIS there is only PZ-90 to choose.

Can anyone explain how to create a proj4 record for these datums?
For PZ-90 proj4 looks like this:

> +proj=longlat +a=6378136 +b=6356751.361745712 +towgs84=0,0,1.5,-0,-0,0.076,0 +no_defs

but I have no knowledge about these values
***towgs84=0,0,1.5,-0,-0,0.076,0 +no_defs***

Comment: maybe related: http://www.navipedia.net/index.php/Reference_Frames_in_GNSS#GLONASS_reference_frame_PZ-90

Answer (score 1):

You can find detail article (on Russian) about toWGS84 transformation on this link: http://gis-lab.info/qa/datum-transform-sets.html

In short - this is 7 parameter coefficients to transform from WGS84 datum to PZ90 datum

Comment: It is what I looked for, thank You. It is intresting why Russian Aviation Service produces on one chart  e.g. 2 different datums PZ90.2 and PZ90.11.